Python error (The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1 class)
I need to make a GMM model and for each distribution i have to train an svm model. This is the code so far. But i get this error (The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1 class).
How can i train each svm with for each distribution?
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC

# Number of centers (distributions)
N = 3

# Generate random data points with different cluster standard deviations
n_samples = 50000
n_features = 2
cluster_std = 1.0

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=n_samples, centers=N, n_features=n_features, 
                  cluster_std=cluster_std, random_state=42)

# Split data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Create and train GMM model
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=N, random_state=42)
gmm.fit(X_train)

# Predict cluster labels for the training set
y_train_pred = gmm.predict(X_train)

# Train an SVM model for each distribution
svms = []
for i in range(N):
    # Filter training samples for the current distribution
    X_train_i = X_train[y_train_pred == i]
    y_train_i = y_train[y_train_pred == i]
    
    # Train SVM for the current distribution
    svm = SVC(kernel='linear', random_state=42)
    svm.fit(X_train_i, y_train_i)
    svms.append(svm)
    

# Save the trained SVM models for future use
import joblib
for i, svm in enumerate(svms):
    joblib.dump(svm, f'svm_model_distribution_{i}.pkl')

print("Training of SVMs is complete.")


Post the complete error message.
